# Adding Sheets With Sequential Names

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I need to write a macro that adds a new sheet when executed. The sheet name will be "Combined-n" where n is an integer. I want it to try add a new sheet named "Combined-1". However, if the sheet "Combined-1" already exists (since this macro can be executed multiple times), I want it to add a sheet called "Combined-2" and so on. I tried a few different things including the code below, but when I execute it nothing happens.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
WS.Activate
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
If WS.Name = "Combined-" & i Then
Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets("Sheet1")).Name = "Combined-" & i + 1
End If
Next i
Next WS
```

I also tried:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
   If Worksheets(i).Name = "Combined-" & i Then
   Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets("Sheet1")).Name = "Combined-" & i + 1
End If
Next i
```

Comment: What would happen when you have `Combine-1` and `Combined-3`? Would the next one be `Combined-2` or `Combined-4`? Or do you need to rename sheets first?

Comment: @JvdV Sorry I should have clarified. Any sheet name "Combined-n" would only exist if I added it with this macro. So after I run it the first time, only "Combined-1" would exist and after the 2nd time, "Combined-1" and "Combined-2" would also exist.

Comment: One problem is that "after the 2nd time" may or may not be in the same host session (e.g. Excel was closed & re-opened between the two runs), and no global or static variable is going to remember what the last value was.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I see what you mean. I think I can say confidently though that based on the model I am building, the macro would only be used the first time the file was opened. In this case, it is safe to assume Excel closing doesn't need to be taken into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function whose only job is to return the name of the next "Combined-N" sheet. I'd do this by counting the number of sheets that have a name that starts with "Combined-", and adding 1 to that number, and then incrementing until "Combined-" concatenated with that number is a sheet name that doesn't already exist.

So, I'd have a `GetNextCombinedSheetName` function to do this, and a `SheetNameExists` function to determine whether a given sheet name exists in an optionally-specified `Workbook`'s `Worksheets` collection.

Something like this:

```
Public Function GetNextCombinedSheetName() As String
    Const namePrefix As String = "Combined-"

    Dim currentcount As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left(ws.Name, Len(namePrefix)) = namePrefix Then
            currentCount = currentCount + 1
        End If
    Next

    Dim nextName As String
    Do 'ensure the name doesn't already exist - increment if it does:
        nextName = namePrefix & currentCount + 1
    Loop While SheetNameExists(nextName)

    GetNextCombinedSheetName = nextName
End Function

Private Function SheetNameExists(ByVal sheetName As String, Optional ByVal wb As Workbook = Nothing) As Boolean
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next ' swallow index out of bounds error 9
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(sheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    SheetNameExists = Not ws Is Nothing
End Function
```

With that, you can add a new sheet and just name it:

```
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
newSheet.Name = GetNextCombinedSheetName
```

Note how every `Worksheets` member call (or `Sheets` - but why are you using the two interchangeably and inconsistently?) is properly qualified with a `Workbook` object: your code appears to have several [implicit ActiveWorkbook references](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveWorkbookReference), and this only works because the `ActiveWorkbook` *happens to be* the host `ThisWorkbook` document - it may not always be the case (especially as you learn to stop `Activate`-ing and `Select`-ing things), and you don't want your code to assume it is: life is much simpler when we systematically qualify workbook and worksheet member calls.

Comment: I appreciate it Mathieu. I tried running the code, but I'm getting an error with the GetNextCombinedSheetName function. I get the errors "While without wend" and "Do without loop". Could you help me figure out how to fix these errors?

Comment: @chrisphils26 sorry, untested air-code - that `While {condition}` should have been `Loop While {condition}`; edited. Also the `Not` was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

@chrisphils26 - you can try below code also

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetAvailableSheeName()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim temp_sht
Dim sht_name, last_sht As String
Dim shtNumber
Dim temp_counter, loop_i, counter, num As Integer

Const Available_sht As String = "Combined-"

temp_counter = 0
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If LCase(Left(sht.name, Len(Available_sht))) = LCase(Available_sht) Then

        shtNumber = Split(sht.name, "-")(1)

        If IsNumeric(shtNumber) Then
            If shtNumber > temp_counter Then
                temp_counter = shtNumber
                last_sht = sht.name
            End If

        Else
            sht_name = sht.name

        End If

    Else
            sht_name = sht.name
    End If

Next sht

If temp_counter = 0 Then

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(sht_name)).name = "Combined-1"
Else

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(last_sht)).name = "Combined-" & temp_counter + 1

    For loop_i = 1 To temp_counter + 1

        For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
             counter = 0
             If LCase("Combined-") & loop_i = LCase(sht.name) Then

               counter = 1
               Exit For
             End If

        Next sht

         If counter = 0 Then
            If loop_i = 1 Then
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets(1)).name = "Combined-" & loop_i
            Else
              num = loop_i - 1
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Combined-" & num)).name = "Combined-" & loop_i
            End If

         End If

        Next loop_i
End If

End Sub
```